# Let the docker daemon add rules to the firewall automaticly

Tags: docker, daemon

Docker creates firewall rules for published port. https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

For remote control of the docker daemon i added the following to the /etc/docker/daemon.json file:

```
{
  "hosts": [
    "tcp://server:2375",
    "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  ]
}
```

I would have expected that docker adds a new rule for this port on the firewall too, but it didnt seem to work.

What did i miss?

Comment: **Don't do this.**  It opens up unrestricted unauthenticated root access to your system.  Anyone can do `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://your.host.ip:2375 docker run -v /:/host cat /etc/passwd` or worse, whenever they can reach your host over the network.  At any rate, in this case, Docker doesn't change the iptables rules at all.

Comment: i followed the instructions here to secure it, https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/#create-a-ca-server-and-client-keys-with-openssl
i just let those parts out of the json above.